# nginx reverse prroxy gives 404s on everything

Tags: apache, nginx, memcached, http-status-code-404, backend

This project is generally served with apache but I want to introduce nginx as a front controller to proxy requests through to memcached or fall back to apache if the URI is not found as a key in memcached.

What is happening when I make the request through nginx is I get 404s on every asset. I can paste a single asset URL from a request right in the URL bar and retrieve it, but with a 404 status. The 404s cause most of the page not to render but it seems the assets are being downloaded.

I can make the same request straight through apache and it works perfectly.

Here is my nginx config:

```
upstream memcached-upstream {
        server 127.0.0.1:11211;
}
upstream apache-upstream {
        server 127.0.0.1:5678; 
}

server {
        listen 4567;
        root    /vagrant;
        server_name sc;
        index index.php;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/www.sc.com.access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/www.sc.com.error.log error;

      location / {
      # Only use this method for GET requests.
      if ($request_method != GET ) {
        proxy_pass http://apache-upstream;
        break;
      }

      # Attempt to fetch from memcache. Instead of 404ing, use the @fallback internal location
      set $memcached_key $request_uri;
      memcached_pass memcached-upstream; # Use an upstream { } block for memcached resiliency
      default_type application/json; # Our services only speak JSON
      error_page 404 = @fallback;
    }

    location @fallback {
      proxy_pass http://apache-upstream;
  }
}
```

here is a sample from my nginx access log:

```
10.0.2.2 - - [18/Dec/2013:23:50:08 +0000] "GET /templates/assets/js/csrf.js HTTP/1.1" 404 545 "http://localhost:4567/templates/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36"
```

And the same request from the apache log:

```
www.sc.com:80 127.0.0.1 - - [18/Dec/2013:23:50:08 +0000] "GET /templates/assets/js/csrf.js HTTP/1.0" 200 857 "http://localhost:4567/templates/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36"
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try replacing the `error_page` with this

```
error_page 404 =200 @fallback;
```